# How to interpret "кому какая легче дается"?

Tags: значения

> Я бы не сказала, что она сложнее сама по себе – **кому какая легче дается**.

I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around the construction/meaning of this phrase, or more specifically, "кому" and "какая".

> =??? It's not that *A* per se is necessarily more difficult – it comes more naturally to some people, after all.

Comment: "whichever (какая) is easier to whomever (кому)" - this is not exactly English, but i hope comprehensible nonetheless, in unpacked version "one comes more naturally to some people, while another comes more naturally to other people"

Comment: @БаянКупи-ка Oh, so this phrasing is quite colloquial, I take it?

Comment: yes indeed.....

Comment: it's possible to combine different relative pronouns in different cases, just random examples: (смотря) кому что (нравится); смотря кому куда (идти); смотря кто где сидит; (смотря) кто чем увлекается; смотря кому с кем работать, смотря что на чём жарить; etc. etc.

Comment: @БаянКупи-ка I see. Can I interpret this construction as "Я бы не сказала, что она сложнее сама по себе – (***It's a matter/question of***) кому какая легче дается"?

Comment: yes, or ***depending*** which is a translation of ***смотря*** implied here

Comment: @БаянКупи-ка So the full sentence would be like: "Я бы не сказала, что она сложнее сама по себе – **а (я бы сказала,)** кому какая легче дается". I mean, in the sense that: "it's not that ..., ***but rather*** ...".

Comment: not necessarily, your previous suggestion is apter, "Я бы не сказала, что она сложнее сама по себе, (скорее) (всё) зависит от того/(весь) вопрос в том, кому какая легче даётся", so yes, ***rather*** is correct

Comment: Or: "Я бы не сказала, что она сложнее сама по себе – **(дело же в том,)** кому какая легче дается"?

Comment: i don't think it fits the puprort of the sentence, же here has contrastive function, but (despite agreement with the use of rather) i don't find contrast in the sentence, rather elaboration; in this funсtion же is synonymous with contrastive conjunctions "а" and "но", but elevates the stylistic register of a phrase making it sound kind of solemnish and exaggerated, which isn't suitable for mundane conversations

Comment: Consider a phrase, like a team needs to complete some sets of tasks, so they have to somehow distribute and assign them, inside the group. "Пусть каждый выберет себе по задаче, смотря кому что/какая легче даётся". Would such a phrase be parsable for you?

Comment: Those two internal sentences are very loosely coupled. They convey a very generic idea with many ways you can complete them. It is not even a shortened form. Those are really just two related ideas spoken out. And if you would need to word them explicitly and entirely - you can choose any words that would suit you. For example: "Я бы не сказала, что она сложнее сама по себе – (тут вопрос (скорее (в том,))) кому какая легче дается". Or "всё дело в том, кому..." Or "смотреть надо, кому...". Or "зависит от того, кому...". Or ANY other variant.

Comment: There was  now some fixed pattern reduced, that you can restore in that One True way. There are just two very generic and vague ideas expressed briefly, and ANY alternative (more explicit, more wordy) way you would express those two ideas would be equally correct. // Personally, I would translate it using "смотря"="considering". Kind of "It is not that X is most hardest of Xs per se, rather consider who is naturally more tuned to which kind of Xs"

Comment: _I wouldn't say it is complicated in itself[: it's rather about] 'which one is easier (to handle) for whom'._
In Russian version the omitted part in square brackets is replaced with a dash, inviting to look at it differently (since the first part of the sentence uses negation).

Answer (score 1):

We do not know what the topic (referred to by the pronoun "она" is. I am going to assume it is "работа", "work". If so, then the utterance:

> Я бы не сказала, что она сложнее сама по себе – кому какая легче дается.

Means:

> I would not say that it is intrinsically difficult. Different people find different kinds of work easier.

Here is a word-by-word breakdown:

кому--to whom, not in the sense to a specific person but in the sense "to one", "to each one"

какая--"what kind of", here serves as a sort of pronoun to refer to something of the feminine gender such as "работа". Here it means "a certain kind".

легче--more easily

дается--yields (in the sense "The door yielded easily to the pressure of his hand."), comes, gives, responds to effort

So the literal meaning is:

> To each one there is a kind of X which comes more easily.